# python list comprehension (if, continue, break)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make it a habit of creating list comprehensions, and basicly optimize any code I write.
I did this little exercise to find if all digits in a given number is even, when trying to create a list with for loops and if statements i ran into a problem with "continue" & "break".
Can i even insert those flow controls into a list?

I'd love to know how much i can shorten any piece of code.
Here's what i wrote, i'd love to get feedback from you guys.

```
numbers = [str(x) for x in range(0, 10000)]

def is_all_even(nums):
    temp_lst = []
    evens_lst = []
    for x in nums:
        for y in x:
            if int(y) % 2 == 0:
                temp_lst.append(str(y))
                continue
            else:
                break
        if len(''.join(temp_lst[:])) == len(x):
            evens_lst.append(''.join(temp_lst[:]))
        del temp_lst[:]
    print(evens_lst)
```

Comment: If your code already works and you're interested in improving it, try over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In general, list comprehensions are an efficient implementation of the higher-order functions `map` and `filter`. They're not really intended to be a replacement for a `for` loop, though many loops can be re-written into them. The concept of a `break` or a `continue` doesn't really make sense in the context of a `map` or a `filter`, so you cannot include them in a comprehension.

Comment: Well, you can start by not making all those shallow copies of `temp_list`.  You might also try playing around with `any()` and `all()`.

Comment: @aruisdante: `They're not really intended to be a replacement for a for loop` ... this may be incorrect. List Comprehension are efficient when you are generating a list as an expression. Contrasting to an explicit loop, you have to generally append element to a list which is not that efficient. Moreover, a list comprehension can often be formulated as a generator which results in reducing overhead of intermediate lists.

Comment: You should split your code into two functions: one that tells if a number is 'all_even' and another that manages the list; using list-comprehension or not is a secondary issue

Comment: @Abhijit: Appending to a list runs in amortized constant time, so it has the same complexity class as a list comprehension.  Furthermore, the construction of the list behind the scenes in a comprehension is likely to have similar amortized behavior, since it doesn't know how long the list will be in advance.

Comment: @Kevin: In case of calling the append method, there is an overhead in the function call. You might argue that both eventually calls LIST_APPEND, but adding a function call overhead often kills the performance. Try to find the difference between the byte code of a LC and a loop expression and you will understand the argument.

Comment: @Abhijit: This is the kind of micro-optimization you should avoid in Python unless and until you've run it through `cProfile` and verified it truly is a problem.  Until then, you should just write whatever's clearest.

Comment: @Abhijit You're correct, but that's still an expression of the higher-order functions `map` and `filter`, not the general case of a `for` loop. To put it another way, list comprehensions are a very efficiently implemented form of `map(func, filter(test, lst))`. You can *always* rewrite a list-comprehension as a for-loop, but you can't always rewrite a for-loop as a list comprehension (nor should you, even in some instances where you can). And a list-comprehension will generally be slower than a for-loop in the cases where you don't actually need the resultant list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a list comp,using [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to find the numbers that contain all even digits:

```
print([s for s in numbers if all(not int(ch) % 2 for ch in s)])
```

`all` will short circuit on finding any odd digit.

If you don't want to store all the numbers in memory at once you can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
evens = (s for s in numbers if all(not int(ch) % 2 for ch in s))
```

To access the numbers you just need to iterate over evens:

```
for n in evens:
    print(n)
```

You could also use filter for a functional approach which returns an iterator in python 3:

```
In [5]: evens = filter(lambda x: all(not int(ch) % 2 for ch in x), numbers)

In [6]: next(evens)
Out[6]: '0'

In [7]: next(evens)
Out[7]: '2'

In [8]: next(evens)
Out[8]: '4'

In [9]: next(evens)
Out[9]: '6'
```

Comment: Depending on OP's needs, they might want a generator expression instead.

Comment: Since we're in Python 3, you can print with `print(*evens, sep='\n')`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, if the OP wants to use the values they will need to iterate over evens, you could also use str.join in python 2  if you just wanted to print.

Comment: Yes, this is for when `evens` has already been saved. `for x in iterable: print(x)` has the same result as `print(*iterable, sep='\n')`.

Answer (score 5):

```
[x for x in range(10000) if all(c in '02468' for c in str(x))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than sending the whole list of numbers to the function, you can send just one number to a function and then use the list comprehension to apply it to your list.

```
def is_all_even(num):
    return all(ch in '02468' for ch in str(num))

print([n for n in range(10000) if is_all_even(n)])
```